# PHP Bootstrap ending a row for different grid sizes

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following grid layout for a list of users:

```
col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2
```

Before I only used `col-md-2` and used a `$counter` to determine when I need to start a new row, and when to end the existing one:

```
    while ($row = $business_query->fetch_assoc()){
        if ($counter % USERS_PER_ROW == 0){
            $business_div .= "<div class=\"row\">";    
        }

        $business_div .= "<div class=\"col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 user-container vertical-align\">
            <a href=\"#\">
                <div class=\"user-content\">
                    <div class=\"user-img\">
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"user-text v-h-align\">"
                    .$row["username"].
                    "</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>";

    if ($counter % USERS_PER_ROW == USERS_PER_ROW - 1 || $counter == $num_business - 1){
        $business_div .= "</div>";
    }
    $counter++;
```

I would just set `USERS_PER_ROW = 6;` and everything would be fine. But how do I do it dynamically when I have 4 different layouts?

Comment: Why not just having a single row? Bootstrap content wil wrap automatically.

Comment: yes that worked tnx a lot... still interested how would one do it if multiple rows are needed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a single row, bootsrtap will wrap columns dynamically. Afaik, its not possible to so what you want in PHP alone, since what you want is done on client side by boottrap, PHP has no idea wether it is xs or sm, or lg.

What i sometimes do, if i want a certain number of cols per row, for a specific size, i do modulus operation on index, and insert br for that view size, like:

```
<br class="clearfix visible-xs-block">
```

This will make a cut, or you can make it a div instead of br, a divider that will be visible on that specific screen size only.